# Graph Plot On Time Shift of Cosine Signal Hanning Function

Tags: continuous-signals, window-functions

I am plotting time shift of the Hanning function. I find few plot result that I am not able to understand. Therefore I would like to ask my question here. The given Hanning function is:

$$
x(t)={\tt hann}(t)=\tfrac{1}{2}  [1+\cos(\pi t)],{\rm\ with} |t| \leq 1
$$

When I use Desmos to plot the time shift function, I find a result that I am not able to understand.

When I enter the function definition and ${\tt hann}(t-2)$ separately, the graph looks fine as below.

[image]

However the graph looks awkward when I plug in $(t-2)$ into the function definition[image]

Somehow I find it looks fine again when I take out $-2$ from $\cos$[image]

Again, when I enter the function definition and ${\tt hann}(t-3)$ separately, the graph looks fine as below:

[image]

Unlike ${\tt hann}(t-2)$ graph, the graph looks awkward when take out $-3$ from $\cos$
[image]

However, the graph looks fine when I plug in $(t−3)$ into the function definition
[image]

Therefore, I would like to ask is there any reason behind causes these kind of result? May I know where I can find more information about this result?

Answer (score 1):

> However the graph looks awkward when I plug in $(t-2)$

First of all, $hann(x-a)$ is equal to

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\big[1+\cos\big(\pi\left(x-a\right)\big)\big]
\end{equation}

contrary to what you have written,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\big[1+\cos\big(\pi x-a\big)\big]
\end{equation}

[image: The red curve is your y(h-3)]

> Somehow I find it looks fine again when I take out −2 from cos

When you change the domain so that the distance of any even number $2k$ from $x$ is less than one, it means $x$ has values between two consecutive odd numbers,

\begin{align}
|x-2k| &\le 1 \\
2k-1 \le x &\le 2k+1
\end{align}

In the instance of $hann(x)$ the boundaries are going to be zero since

\begin{equation}
\cos\big((2k\pm1)\pi\big) = -1
\end{equation}

hence you get the same bell shaped curve.

[image]

In fact, you can have $hann(x-2n)$ and this still holds true since the difference between an odd and an even integer is an odd integer.

[image]

> Unlike (−2) graph, the graph looks awkward when take out −3 from cos

Based on the previous explanation, you can now probably infer the reason why the curve gets flipped horizontally.